# Laptop screen not working with nvidia but external screens do

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

##### Problem:

Originally installed Fedora - couldn't get the external screens to work but the laptop one was fine (with nvidia drivers). Switched to Ubuntu 20.04 and the external screens (HDMI and DP) work great but the laptop either flickers or goes completely white. Both the external screens and the laptop work fine in Win 11.

##### Specs:

ASUS TUF A15 and NVIDIA GeoForce RTX 3050 Ti (535.86.05)

##### Tried:

- No xorg.conf file
- Various version of downlevel nvidia drivers (if I switch to noveau only the laptop screen works - the others act as if disconnected
- Various 535 nvidia versions from the Additional Drivers in the Software & Updates app
- Tried Ubuntu Pro and non-pro

##### Details:

`lspci`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rembrandt (rev c8)
0
```

`xrandr --prop`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000dae3c1500000000
        041f0104a52213780328659759548e27
        1e505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101019e8580a070383e403020
        a50058c110000018ad3780a070383e40
        3020a50058c110000018000000fd0030
        90a5a522010a202020202020000000fe
        004e313536484d452d47414b0a200046
    GAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    DEGAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    GAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    CTM: 579596464 1 1089267271 -2147483648 469448672 0 334778912 -2147483648 1124858831 1 778394941 -2147483648 76311147 -2147483648 152277357 -2147483648 
        242683635 1 
    DEGAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    vrr_capable: 1 
        range: (0, 1)
    abm level: 0 
        range: (0, 4)
    max bpc: 16 
        range: (8, 16)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 78 
        supported: 78
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080    144.00*+  60.00  
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1440x900     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00  
   1024x768     144.00  
   800x600      144.00  
   640x480      144.00  
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff00220e6c3601010101
        251f010380351e782a0565a756529c27
        0f5054a10800d1c0a9c081c0b3009500
        810081800101023a801871382d40582c
        45000f282100001e000000fd00304b1e
        5612000a202020202020000000fc0048
        502032346d680a2020202020000000ff
        0033434d313337304d5052202020012d
        020321f149901f041303120211012309
        07078301000067030c001000001ee200
        6b023a801871382d40582c45000f2821
        00001e023a80d072382d40102c45800f
        282100001e011d007251d01e206e2855
        000f282100001e011d00bc52d01e20b8
        2855400f282100001e2a4480a0703827
        40302035000f282100001a00000000b6
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    PRIME Synchronization: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
    CTM: 420160213 1 390610691 -2147483648 68657360 -2147483648 4394435 0 -7568605 0 12152591 0 51151133 0 163963301 0 
        -202741000 0 
    CscMatrix: 71947 -5960 -1047 0 67 65420 185 0 780 2501 62442 0 
    BorderDimensions: 4 
        supported: 4
    Border: 0 0 0 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    SignalFormat: TMDS 
        supported: TMDS
    ConnectorType: HDMI 
    ConnectorNumber: 4 
    _ConnectorLocation: 4 
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.97*   59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93
```

`inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] driver: nvidia
    v: 535.86.05
  Device-2: AMD Rembrandt driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,ati,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,radeon,vesa
    gpu: amdgpu resolution: 1: 1920x1080 2: 1920x1080~144Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: REMBRANDT (rembrandt LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-32-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```